# Playing Video from app cache inside a directory

Tags: android, caching, video

I am working on Android 3.1 ,
My problem is that the downloaded video from link to my applications cache directory does not working,
but Working the same downloaded video from the Cache?
The video is being downloaded and  I am saving it into memory application like the following senarios

```
 // Works

 File file = new File(getCacheDir(), "sample.mp4");

 // Does not work

 String RootDir = getCacheDir() + File.separator + "FirstData";
 File RootFile = new File(RootDir);
 RootFile.mkdirs();

 File file = new File(RootFile.getAbsolutePath(), "sample.mp4");
```

If I attempt to play the video and set the path like .

```
 videoview.setVideoPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

and trying to "stream" the video to my VideoView, it is showing sorry can not play the video
and showing the errors like

03-22 12:43:39.898: E/MediaPlayer(1335): error (1, -2147483648)
and also i sets the file permissions like

```
 file.setReadable(true,false);
```

even it showing the same.

but its working fine when the location of video is getCacheDir(), Only the problem with inside cache one more directory i have created and trying to play then the problem is coming.

So Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Hmm, got the same problem here :-( 

Fails if i use getCacheDir, but works with getExternalCacheDir(). Strange...